# Grabbing the return value from execv()

Tags: c, exec, fork, wait

```
//code for foo (run executable as ./a.out)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
int i = 1;
char *parms[] = {"test2", "5", NULL}; //test executable named test2   
if(pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed");
        return 1;
}
else if(pid == 0) {
        printf("Child pid is %d\n", pid);
        i = execv("test2", parms);  //exec call to test with a param of 5
}
else {
        wait(NULL);
}
printf("I is now %d\n", i); //i is still 1 here, why?
return 0;
}
```

Hey everybody, I am trying to learn a little bit about fork and execv() calls. I make my foo.c program above make a call to a file I have named test.c. I fork a child and have the child make a call to execv, which will just add 10 to the parameter read in. I am unsure of why the variable does not change, at the bottom of my foo.c function. Does the call need to be a pointer or return an address? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Code for test.c (executable named test2)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv[]) {
        int i = atoi(argv[1]);
        i = i +10;
        printf("I in test is %d\n", i);
        return i;
}
```

Comment: If you want to grab the return value from child process, you could use IPC method(pipe socket and so on), or even try to exchange data by writing and reading files.

Comment: I had the same file idea too hahaha thats my go to answer for exchanging data :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only call `execv()` in the child process. The `exec()` family functions never return if it runs successfully.  See [evec(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec):

> The `exec()` functions only return if an error has occurred. The return value is `-1`, and `errno` is set to indicate the error.

You printed the value of `i` in the parent process, it never changed in the parent process.

---

To get the exit status from the child process, you can make use of [`wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) or [`waitpid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid):

```
else {
        int waitstatus;
        wait(&waitstatus);
        i = WEXITSTATUS(waitstatus);
}
```

Comment: I read up on exec, thank you. Is there any way to grab a return value from another program that exec creates? I suppose I could read and right the values into a file but that seems like it would be expensive for the CPU.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I thought that the WEXITSTATUS would only return a 1 or a 0 based on whether or not it exited but I was wrong about that.